How do I convert the "information" column from "SHOW TABLE EXTENDED LIKE 'employe*'" example in Azure Databricks? I'd appreciate some inputs
SQL Statement
SHOW TABLE EXTENDED LIKE 'employe*';

OUTPUT:

database tableName isTemporary                          information
 -------- --------- ----------- --------------------------------------------------------------
 default  employee  false       Database: default
                                Table: employee
                                Owner: root
                                Created Time: Fri Aug 30 15:10:21 IST 2019
                                Last Access: Thu Jan 01 05:30:00 IST 1970
                                Created By: Spark 3.0.0
                                Type: MANAGED
                                Provider: hive
                                Table Properties: [transient_lastDdlTime=1567158021]
                                Location: file:/opt/spark1/spark/spark-warehouse/employee
                                Serde Library: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy
                                .LazySimpleSerDe
                                InputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
                                OutputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io
                                .HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
                                Storage Properties: [serialization.format=1]
                                Partition Provider: Catalog
                                Partition Columns: [`grade`]
                                Schema: root
                                  -- name: string (nullable = true)
                                  -- grade: integer (nullable = true)



WHAT I TRIED in PySpark:
I tried to set "allowUnquotedFieldNames" to "true" as the output from SQL statement isn't json/dictonary formatted. I created a schema based on the output. I also thought setting "primitiveAsString" to "true" could also help parsing in all the other characters that are non-Latin.

spark.sql("SHOW TABLE EXTENDED LIKE '*'").withColumn('info1', F.from_json(F.col('info'), schema=schema_json, options={"allowUnquotedFieldNames": "true", "primitiveAsString" : "true", "linesep": "\n"}))


It's resulting in an object field with all nulls.
object
Catalog: null
Database: null
Table: null
Owner: null
Created_Time: null
Last_Access: null
Created_By: null
Type: null
Provider: null
Table_Properties: null
Location: null
Serde_Library: null
InputFormat: null
OutputFormat: null
Parition_Provider: null
Schema: null



To parse the "information" column from the output of SHOW TABLE EXTENDED LIKE 'employee*'
I have tried the below approach:
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_extract
pattern = r"Database:\s*(\w+)\s*Table:\s*(\w+)\s*Owner:\s*(\w+)\s*Created Time:\s*(.*?)\s*Last Access:\s*(.*?)\s*Created By:\s*(.*?)\s*Type:\s*(.*?)\s*Provider:\s*(.*?)\s*Location:\s*(.*?)\s*Serde Library:\s*(.*?)\s*InputFormat:\s*(.*?)\s*OutputFormat:\s*(.*?)\s*Partition Provider:\s*(.*?)\s*Schema:\s*(.*)"
df = spark.sql("SHOW TABLE EXTENDED LIKE 'employe*'").select("information")
df_parsed = df.withColumn('database', regexp_extract(df['information'], pattern, 1)) \
    .withColumn('tableName', regexp_extract(df['information'], pattern, 2)) \
    .withColumn('owner', regexp_extract(df['information'], pattern, 3)) \
    .withColumn('createdTime', regexp_extract(df['information'], pattern, 4)) \
    .withColumn('lastAccess', regexp_extract(df['information'], pattern, 5)) \
    .withColumn('createdBy', regexp_extract(df['information'], pattern, 6)) \
    .withColumn('type', regexp_extract(df['information'], pattern, 7)) \
    .withColumn('provider', regexp_extract(df['information'], pattern, 8)) \
    .withColumn('location', regexp_extract(df['information'], pattern, 9)) \
    .withColumn('serdeLibrary', regexp_extract(df['information'], pattern, 10)) \
    .withColumn('inputFormat', regexp_extract(df['information'], pattern, 11)) \
    .withColumn('outputFormat', regexp_extract(df['information'], pattern, 12)) \
    .withColumn('partitionProvider', regexp_extract(df['information'], pattern, 13)) \
    .withColumn('schema', regexp_extract(df['information'], pattern, 14))
df_parsed = df_parsed.drop('information')
df_parsed.show(truncate=False)

Results:
tableName   database    owner   createdTime lastAccess  createdBy   type    provider    location    serdeLibrary    inputFormat outputFormat    partitionProvider   schema
employee    default root    Fri Aug 30 15:10:21 IST 2019    Thu Jan 01 05:30:00 IST 1970    Spark 3.0.0 MANAGED hive
Table Properties: [transient_lastDdlTime=1567158021]    file:/opt/spark1/spark/spark-warehouse/employee org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat    org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
Storage Properties: [serialization.format=1]    Catalog
Partition Columns: ['grade']    root
  -- name: string (nullable = true)
  -- grade: integer (nullable = true)

In the above code defining a regular expression pattern to match the structure of the 'information' column from the output of the SHOW TABLE EXTENDED command.
Using regexp_extract to parse the 'information' column, given that the data is structured in a consistent format.
Creating a DataFrame containing the 'information' column
